# SecurityException when mapping inheritance with Fluent NHibernate under Medium trust

Tags: c#, nhibernate, medium-trust

I'm having problems mapping inheritance in my application running under Medium trust. It works like a charm when I remove Medium trust restrictions from web.config. If I comment out my subclass mappings, all goes well too.

When my application starts in Medium trust, during Fluent's configuration building, I catch exception from which I can read that System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(...) method has no permissions to run.

Every bit of information I can find suggests pre-generating lazy proxies, turning lazy loading off and disabling reflection optimizer. I've done all that preparation, and my code works if I don't map subclasses.

Here are my mappings:

```
public PageMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.PageID);
        Map(x => x.DateCreated);
        Map(x => x.DateLastAccessed);
        Map(x => x.Hits);
        Map(x => x.PrivateSuffix);
        Map(x => x.PublicSuffix);
        HasMany(x => x.Components).Not.LazyLoad();
        Not.LazyLoad();
    }
}

public class ComponentMap: ClassMap<Component>
{
    public ComponentMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.ComponentID);
        Map(x => x.Position);
        References(x => x.Page);
        DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("ComponentType");
        Not.LazyLoad();
    }
}

public class HeadingComponentMap : SubclassMap<HeadingComponent>
{
    public HeadingComponentMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.Text);
        Not.LazyLoad();
    }
}
```

and a relevant part from web.config

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
<bytecode-provider type="null"/>
<reflection-optimizer use="false" />

<session-factory name="">
  <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
  <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
  <property name="connection.connection_string">data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|entities.mdf;User Instance=true</property>
  <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect</property>
  <property name='proxyfactory.factory_class'>NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
  <property name='current_session_context_class'>web</property>
</session-factory>
```

Will I have to do everything manually? I would very much like to use inheritance here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't able to solve the original problem, but the answer that AlexCuse gave led me to a workaround.

When I change the model I export mappings using

```
.Mappings(
    m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<SessionManager>()
    .ExportTo("mappings")
)
```

and after embedding mappings as resources i map using

```
.Mappings(
    m => m.HbmMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<SessionManager>()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm it seems like you've got your bases covered.  Assuming you've been through [this](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/run-in-medium-trust.aspx), but including just in case.

It sounds like you may have run into an issue with the way fluent NHibernate deals with inheritance.  What version are you running (of both)?  To determine if the problem is specific to fluent or nhibernate's configuration, you might try running something like this when setting up a session factory (in full trust):

```
.Mappings(m =>
{
  m.FluentMappings
    .AddFromAssemblyOf<YourEntity>()
    .ExportTo(@"C:\your\export\path");

  m.AutoMappings
    .Add(/* ... */)
    .ExportTo(@"C:\your\export\path");
})
```

(from http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_configuration)

This will export standard .hbm.xml mapping files that can be used to see if the application will run properly with **just** nhibernate

Answer (score 0):

The problem happens because you are using a SubclassMap<>

Fluent NHibernate (even in the latest code as of October) uses a DeepClone(..) extension method during a subclass mapping operation which internally uses BinaryFormatter to clone the mapping expression, but that cannot run in Medium Trust because it tries to read/write private members.

I haven't fixed Fluent NHibernate (although I am in the process of doing so on a fork) but I have just put up a post just recently on how to unit test code in Medium Trust

Part three has a downloadable assembly with a base class you can use for any NUnit test fixture, and it contains links to the other parts: http://boxbinary.com/2011/10/how-to-run-a-unit-test-in-medium-trust-with-nunitpart-three-umbraco-framework-testing/